# Proof-like environment

Tags: theorems

I have a theorem environment called question, and I would like to use a proof-like environment that prints "Solution" instead of "Proof"

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{question}{Question}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
Some question here
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
Here goes the solution to the question
\end{solution}

\begin{theorem}
Some theorem or formula to derive here
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
Here goes the proof to the question
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

I have used the command `$`\renewcommand{\proofname}{Solution}`$` as a temporary fix, but that replaces the name for all instances, and sometimes I will actually need to use the regular proof environment, with "Proof" as its name.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Package `amsthm` has three styles: `plain` (title is in `\bfseries` and body is in `\itshape`), `definition` (title is in `\bfseries` and body is in `\rmfamily`) and `remark` (title is in `\itshape` and body is in `\rmfamily`).  All of them come with starred versions, which do not use a counter.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{solution}{Solution}


\begin{document}

\begin{question}
Some question here
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
Here goes the solution to the question
\end{solution}

\begin{theorem}
Some theorem or formula to derive here
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
Here goes the proof to the question
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

---

Here is another way if you like to see the `QED` symbol at the end of the solution.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}

\newenvironment{solution}{\renewcommand{\proofname}{Solution}\begin{proof}}{\end{proof}}


\begin{document}

\begin{question}
Some question here
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
Here goes the solution to the question
\end{solution}

\begin{theorem}
Some theorem or formula to derive here
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
Here goes the proof to the question
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't know I could renew a command inside another one, that's really useful

Answer (score 5):

Original `proof` copied and modified:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem} % PS
\newtheorem{question}{Question}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{solution}[1][\solutionname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
%<amsbook|amsproc>  \itemindent\normalparindent
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
%<amsbook|amsproc>        \scshape
%<amsart|amsthm>        \itshape
\itshape 
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
%    \end{macrocode}
%    Default for \cn{proofname}:
%    \begin{macrocode}
\providecommand{\solutionname}{Solution}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{question}
Some question here
\end{question}

%\begin{proof}
\begin{solution} % PS
Here goes the solution to the question
%\end{proof}
\end{solution} % PS

\begin{theorem}
Some theorem or formula to derive here
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
Here goes the proof to the question
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's really interesting for me to see the original code. Can I find this code in the package documentation? I would like to get more familiar with latex internal workings

Comment: @Mahoma You can find it in amsthm.sty, a file called in your code. Modifying original macros is for me much better approach than using macros in nonstandard way.