# fbox typing in Latex

Tags: exam, fbox

[image: Volvo1]
Whats the Latex code for inserting a small boxes at the end of a remark sentence like the ones in the image above?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Are you maybe looking for `\square`, a math-mode macro provided by the `amssymb` package?

Comment: \qed (quod erat demonstrandum).?

Comment: Or even `ΟΕΔ` (ὅπερ ἔδει δεîξαι)? :-)

Comment: Do you agree that the answers to this question answer yours? 
 [\qed for theorems without proofs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34014/138900)

Comment: Thanx, actually \square has done a wonderful job. But \quad , \fbox etc were failing.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328518/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remarks of the image are `proof` environments of `amsthm`. No need to type  directly  the `\qedsymbol`:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,parskip}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
This is classwork, straight from the lectures notes.
\end{proof}

\renewcommand\proofname{Remark}

\begin{proof}
This is classwork, straight from the lectures notes.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
\lipsum[1][1-5]
\end{proof}

With \qedsymbol\ changed to \renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\boxtimes$}\qedsymbol: 

\begin{proof}[Whatever]
\lipsum[2][1-3]
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow thanks, this solved the problems that came when \square seemed to have worked.